# Error writing image to file in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write an image that I do operations on to a '.tif' file in a directory. I make the results directory with Matlab using the mkdir() function.

Here is the command I am using:

```
[pathstr, nameWOext, ext] = fileparts(filename);
results_dir = ['results' '/results_' nameWOext];

%check to see if the directory exists already, if it doesn't make it
if(exist(results_dir) ~= 7)
    mkdir(results_dir);
end

filenamezero = [nameWOext '_J' ext];

imwrite (~J, fullfile(results_dir, filenamezero));  //Error here
```

When Matlab gets to this line it outputs an error:

> Could not open file for writing.  Check directory or file permissions.

I inspected the folder 'results/results_' and the folder is read-only. Apparently `mkdir()` is doing this automatically.

Is there anyway to get around this?

Thanks

P.S. I am running Windows 7 using Matlab 6.1

Comment: I don't know why it's being created as read-only, but you could try calling `fileattrib(results_dir,'+w')` after creating it.

Comment: I just tried that I still receive the same error. I even manually setting the folder permissions to read/write and the same error persisted.

Comment: Is it on a different filesystem/partition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem may be your use of the `fullfile` function. I think the result is that the path you are trying to pass to `imwrite` has a mix of `\` and `/` for file separators.

Try using this instead:

```
filenamezero = [nameWOext '_J' ext];
imwrite (~J, [results_dir '/' filenamezero]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I never would have thought any thing was wrong with that. But `fullfile()` was the culprit

Comment: I tried it on a newer version of Matlab and they seem to have fixed it. I'm glad you got it working, though!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Matlab, when using an absolute path, requires to use ' / ' instead of the ' \ '.

For example, this works for me (Windows 8.1, Matlab R2012b)

```
imwrite(imagename, 'C:/Users/Myworkingfolder/myimage1.jpg','jpg');
```

But not:

```
imwrite(imagename, 'C:\Users\Myworkingfolder.jpg','jpg');
```

And this, even if Windows itself uses the ' \ ' when you copy a path from Windows explorer.

Although, when using a relative path, such as writing in the current folder in Matlab:

```
imwrite(imagename, 'Myworkingfolder/myimage1.jpg','jpg');
```

and

```
imwrite(imagename, 'Myworkingfolder\myimage1.jpg','jpg');
```

It works out of the box. It might be with how both cases (absolute and relative paths) are implemented...